# Best practice for handling thousands of circle markers with leaflet

Tags: javascript, performance, maps, leaflet, geojson

I'm drawing a large number of markers (~3,000), and for performance reasons, would like to have the ability to only draw the markers which are in the visible area.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put your points into a spatial index, and query that index each time the map's bounds changes, adding and removing markers as you move.

One such spatial index is [RBush](https://github.com/mourner/rbush) by Vladimir Agafonkin / mourner, the author of Leaflet.

Having said that, it might not be worth it for 3000 markers, which most clients should be able to handle.

You might also want to look at [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) if you haven't already. It can handle very large amounts of markers.